# How to add a new method to Array.prototype for a specific case

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-chain

Define a method on Array prototype called `includesOneOf` which should accept an array as a parameter and should return either true or false, based on if an array contains one or more than one of the elements provided in the parameter array.
As a result of this we should be able to access something like:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];  

arr.includesOneof([2, 8, 10]) //output: true  
arr.includesOneof([10, 11, 12]) //output: false  
arr.includesOneof([]) //output: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding methods to the prototype is not recommended here.
The behaviour you are expecting can be easily achieved by

1. Creating a function(maybe create at a global place if you need it across the files or export the function if the codebase allows that).
2. Put the logic to return boolean in the function.
3. Call the function wherever needed.

```js
function includesOneof(mainArray, arrayToLookupFor) {
  return mainArray.some(ele => arrayToLookupFor.includes(ele));
}

const mainArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arr1 = [2, 8, 10];
const arr2 = [10, 11, 12];
const arr3 = [];

const result1 = includesOneof(mainArray, arr1);
console.log(result1);

const result2 = includesOneof(mainArray, arr2);
console.log(result2);

const result3 = includesOneof(mainArray, arr2);
console.log(result3);
```

If you still want to add it to the array prototype then, that can be done like this

```js
Array.prototype.includesOneof = function (arrayToLookupFor) {
    return this.some(ele => arrayToLookupFor.includes(ele))
}

const mainArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arr1 = [2, 8, 10];
const arr2 = [10, 11, 12];
const arr3 = [];

const result1 = mainArray.includesOneof(arr1);
console.log(result1);

const result2 = mainArray.includesOneof(arr2);
console.log(result2);

const result3 = mainArray.includesOneof(arr3);
console.log(result3);
```